# Sending a dictionary of javascript parameters to MVC Controller via JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I'm using a third party library and cant really change the way it posts data to my MVC 5 controller.

I cant figure out how to setup my model to receive the data.

The json is a follows...

```
{
 "expiration":"2015-06-14T21:02:52.969Z",
 "conditions":[
   {"acl":"private"},
   {"bucket":"anyoldbucket"},
   {"Content-Type":"application/pdf"},
   {"success_action_status":"200"},
   {"key":"somekey"}
  ]
}
```

I tried setting up my model like this...

```
public class AwsSignatureRequestViewModel
{
    public DateTime expiration { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> conditions { get; set; }
 }
```

The expiration date is correctly filled out, and I get the right number of conditions but the keys to the dictionary are numbers (indexes) and the values are null

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using JSON.NET?

Comment: You might have to create a separate model for Condition and add the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model is strict, you will need to make objects for every sub objects.
But if you have a dynamic model, you can read the raw string from your request and parse it with Json.net.

```
public ActionResult Test(string model)
{
  Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  string jsonData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
  var dynamicObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
  ...
}
```

dynamicObject will contains all of your json.

Comment: Thanks I was able to add this line to get the data into my model. 

var model = dynamicObject.ToObject<AwsSignatureRequestViewModel>();

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to put the line of code to convert to your model.

Answer (score 0):

IINM, based on the data you're getting, your `AwsSignatureRequestViewModel` should look something like this:

```
public class AwsSignatureRequestViewModel
{
    public DateTime expiration { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> conditions { get; set; }
}
```

`conditions` is an "array of objects".

The way you currently have your model, data would map to something like this (which isn't the case):

```
{
  "expiration": "2015-06-14T21:02:52.969Z",
  "conditions": 
   {
      "acl": "private",
      "bucket": "anyoldbucket",
       ....
   },
   .....
```

Hth...

Comment: This does work but the solution below by Demonia works better for my use case as I can get a single dictionary with the results I need rather than an array of dictionaries, thanks though

Comment: @PhilipHey Sure whatever works. Though _depending on your use case_, then you _may_ not even need to use a `controller` because at the end of the day all you really needed was to get to the Request stream data (not via some "model"). Hth..